# Preferred namespace naming convention

Tags: .net, visual-studio, namespaces, namespace-organisation

i've recently refactored a medium sized application and one of the jobs was to split commonly used code to different projects.

Now, lets say that commonly used namespace structure is

`Core.Interfaces` - for the main application
with an interface of `IFoo`

and for each specialized/external/referenced assembly i decided to make an extension to that, like

`Core.Interfaces.Html` 
with an interface of `IBar`

the main application's `Core` assembly is located in a project named `Core` with a default namespace of `Core` while for the `Html` assembly i made a project named `HtmlCore` with a default namespace of `Core`.

The result effect (and the reason i selected this particular methodology) is that once you have referenced the `Html` assembly the `using` statements would not have to be updated and the net effect is

```
Core.Interfaces.IFoo fooIf;
Core.Interfaces.Html.IBar barIf;
```

or with a using statement of `Core.Interfaces` the above is transformed to

```
IFoo fooIf;
Html.IBar barIf;
```

This *implicit* namespace structure is a direct result of dependencies and it really has served us well as it makes project namespace maintenance a lot easier and the only thing someone has to have is the reference to the assembly. The structure is similar to what microsoft already does on the .net framework.

The thing is that i have second thoughts and (for future projects) i am considering a namespace structure that is explicit for each assembly like:

```
Core.DataInterfaces
Html.Core.DataInterfaces
```

So, has anyone worked with the *explicit* structure, both or even something else i haven't tried? I am open to suggestions and i am searching for the best solution as the target is to free up time from maintenance and confusion in the team during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organize your namespaces however you see fit for your projects. Namespaces are for logical separation to avoid nameing collisions but are obviously great for organizing your code.

Remember, you can always give usings an alias.